# Can't mount partitions!

Tags: mount, windows, ntfs

I have currently installed **Debian** in my system **alongside Windows 8.1**. I have a problem in mounting my other partitions in debian. When trying to open it the following error pops up:

`` Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/amit/New Volume: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/amit/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option. ``

I could however mount the partitions read only from the terminal

Comment: Isn't the error message quite clear?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did shutdown my windows completely but the error still pertains. Is there something else that I should do?

Comment: I never used Windows so cannot help. But did you consider to use *Ext3* file system on your shared disk. There are some Ext3 drivers for Windows, and it is very common on Linux.

Comment: I will certainly look at that. Anyways thanks for your time :)

Comment: Is there any way to run a `chkdsk`  (or other `fsck` equivalent) under Windows?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I ran chkdsk in windows but no problems found.

Comment: Then reboot again Linux and try again.

Comment: Oh good Lord! It worked. thanks @BasileStarynkevitch. But what did really happen here?!

Comment: It's clear to me. Your [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) was dirty, and now it is clean.

Comment: BTW, why do you need Windows? For gaming? I never needed Windows (and my first program was in PL/1 for OS/VS2 on IBM/370/168, on punched cards, in 1975)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Okay. But if you could post this as an answer I could close my question. Thanks again :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I actually started out late in linux :) so thought maybe windows might come handy in case if I get really stuck. Just like now. :)

Comment: I answered, but I am still curious. Why do you need Windows?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How else could you run Micro$oft Office?? The horror. /s

Comment: Never used it. Libreoffice, LaTeX, Lout....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, the ([NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)) [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) was dirty, as the error message was saying.

So checking it (on Windows) with a `chkdsk` command (or the Windows equivalent of *fsck*) -to clean it- then rebooting Linux could be enough.

If you absolutely need Windows with some data shared with Linux, you could consider using an [Ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) (or Ext3) file system (shared with Linux) on Windows, perhaps using (on Windows) [ext2fsd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/)

Answer (score 2):

Further to Basile's answer, once you are able to successfully mount the ntfs partition you may need a driver such as [ntfs-3g](http://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/) in order to be able to write/copy data from it.

Comment: Thanks for that bit :) i already have it in the system but didn't know that it was the reason I could write/copy from the ntfs partition.

Comment: No problem, it caught me out on a fresh Arch install where I could mount and read but not write any data on an ntfs drive.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message notes, it's often caused by Windows's Hybrid Boot(tm) aka fast startup. It's sort of midway between hibernation and normal shutdown and often leaves drives dirty. [Disable it](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) if you run into this problem again.